# Multiple LEFT JOINS in dbf (dBase)

Tags: c#, left-join, oledb, dbase

I am trying to run a query on dbf files in C# using OLEDB like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 USING ID
LEFT JOIN table3 USING ID
```

But I get en error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"

Tried to execute the same query in Corel Paradox - it works!

Comment: You might find the FoxPro drivers to be faster and it might be more SQL compliant. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=foxpro+dbase+odbc&oq=foxpro+dbase+odbc&aqs=chrome..69i57.9015j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I have to change it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM ((table1)
LEFT JOIN table2 USING ID)
LEFT JOIN table3 USING ID
```

I've found an article on same issue that occured in MS Access

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that if using a FoxPro based driver, and probably the OleDB driver in general does not support the USING clause.  You probably need to explicitly use the ON command.

```
SELECT *
   FROM table1
      LEFT JOIN table2 
         on table1.ID = table2.ID
      LEFT JOIN table3 
         on table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Comment: No, it acts the same way, the clue is to use brackets.